# ROWS BETWEEN function in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure why I'm getting this error.

Query:

```
SELECT
    TURBINE, YR, MO, D,
    AVG(Z_SCORE) OVER (PARTITION BY TURBINE ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN 13 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ROLLINGAVG
FROM 
    #ORDERED
```

Sample Data

```
Rowno    Turbine     Yr     Mo  D    Z_Score
--------------------------------------------------------
5153    KV#G04_25   2016    5   27  0.530932540472319 
5154    KV#I11_47   2016    5   27  -0.0887050712447865 
5155    KV#B04_08   2016    5   27  0.983732236771842 
5156    KV#B05_09   2016    5   27  0.0127747723017027
```

ERROR:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 75
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'

Most errors regarding this error are about using an older version of SQL Server but I'm using 2014. ROWS should work fine.

I've also tried this without the partition by and used a group by instead. That also didn't work. Any time there's "OVER" and "ROWS" I get an error.

Comment: can you show the columns in `#ORDERED` table?

Comment: Also, some sample data for `#ORDERED` would be helpful.

Comment: Yes @vkp

ROWNO TURBINE YR MO D Z_SCORE

Comment: 5153 KV#G04_25 2016 5 27 0.530932540472319
5154 KV#I11_47         2016 5 27 -0.0887050712447865
5155 KV#B04_08 2016 5 27 0.983732236771842
5156 KV#B05_09 2016 5 27 0.0127747723017027

Comment: i see..you are using `avg` which doesn't need an `order by`. just use `AVG(Z_SCORE) OVER (PARTITION BY TURBINE)`.

Comment: that's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Your query works fine for me (without error at least) with the test data you have supplied - perhaps you can confirm the exact schema of the `#ORDERED` table so we can see what datatype each column has?

Comment: @vkp order by causes no errors.

Comment: ROWNO was provided by Row_Number() function in another query.
D, MO, and YR were extracted from a datetime previously
Z_Score was calculated and is shown in a float

There are some NULL Z_Scores

Comment: I used your test data and ran the query. I did NOT get any error on SQL Server 2012. Hence, it is definitely not the case here. The only thing I can think of is this: What make you think you are using SQL Server 2014? What is returned by this statement: SELECT @@VERSION;

Comment: Check if comp.level >= 110            SELECT name,compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases.

Comment: @DimaSUN shows comp level of 100. What does it mean if comp level is below 110?

Comment: @OmarAli - comp.level 100 means that you use sql 2008 commands. Over in 2008 didn't contained rows option. try to change comp.level to 110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks good to me, are you working on a database in a Pre 2012 compatibility level? not all functionality is avilable in older versions of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The query worked for me in SQL Server 2016 with the sample data provided.

```
SELECT  TURBINE
,       YR
,       MO
,       D
,       AVG(Z_SCORE) OVER ( PARTITION BY TURBINE ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN 13 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS ROLLINGAVG
FROM    #ORDERED;
```